# objdump, displaying without offsets

Tags: objdump

When dumping an executable file, I only want the code segment to be printed on the standard output, not offsets and binary form of the code. I cannot achieve it from

```
man objdump
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can suppress the object code hex dump with

```
--no-show-raw-insn
```

If you have jumps in the code then you need the offsets to make sense of them, but if you really want to strip them, filter the code with something like:

```
objdump -d --no-show-raw-insn myfile.o | perl -p -e 's/^\s+(\S+):\t//;'
```

Example output:

```
0000000000000000 <foo>:
retq
lea    0x0(%rsi),%rsi
lea    0x0(%rdi),%rdi
Disassembly of section .gnu.linkonce.t.goo:

0000000000000000 <goo>:
retq
lea    0x0(%rsi),%rsi
lea    0x0(%rdi),%rdi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve same output as ***Peeter Joot*** showed but without using **Perl** command line. Then you can use **Grep** and **Cut** tool instead, like shown below.

```
objdump -d --no-show-raw-insn my_binary_file.o | grep "^ " | cut -f2,3
```